# Modifying Ints in ArrayList of IntLists

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

In processing, I am attempting to create an ArrayList of IntLists such that the initial number of Elements in the ArrayList is variable to begin with (but I will not change it in the code) and the number of elements in the IntList is initially 0 but will be added to and edited within the code.
My code is a Japanese Ladder game where the ArrayList is of Ladders, each of which has an IntList containing "Rungs" which are int components that correspond to a Y location on the ladder.

```
ArrayList <IntList> Ladders = new ArrayList <IntList>();
IntList temp = new IntList();

void setup()
{
  for(int i=0;i<numRails-1;i++)
  {
    Ladders.add(new IntList());
    temp.clear();
    temp.append(0);
    Ladders.set(i,temp);
  }
}
void addRung (int spot)
{
  temp.clear();
  temp = Ladders.get(spot);
  temp.append(50);
  //note that 50 is an arbitrary number, it would be given by MouseY
  Ladders.set(spot,temp);
  print(Ladders);

  //I have also tried...
  Ladders.get(spot).append(50);
}
```

So my problem is that addRung() seems to add 50 to every single element ofthe ArrayList and "print(Ladders);" outputs...

```
[IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ], IntList size=1 [ 50 ]]
```

Is there a better way to go about this entirely or am I doing something wrong?

I included an image of what my code is outputting... It should be a single rung at location 50 but it is 9 rungs at 50.

[image]

Comment: You're creating a single IntList adding it 50 times to the ArrayList. You need 50 different IntLists.

Comment: How could I write my addRung() function to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please think carefully about exactly what this code is doing:

```
for(int i=0;i<numRails-1;i++)
  {
    Ladders.add(new IntList());
    temp.clear();
    temp.append(0);
    Ladders.set(i,temp);
  }
```

Here you're adding a new `IntList` to your `Ladders` `ArrayList`. Then you're clearing `temp` and adding `0` to it, and then you're setting the index (which you just added a new `IntList` to) to `temp`, which replaces the new `IntList` you just added.

In other words, you're adding `temp` to every index of the `ArrayList`. That's just a bunch of references to the same `IntList`, which is why when you add a value to one index, it adds the value to every index.

To fix this, you need to get rid of your `temp` variable completely. Just add a new `IntList` to each index, and then use the `get()` function to get the `IntList` from the index in the `ArrayList`. It would look like this:

```
ladders.get(index).append(value);
```

As a side note, you should really get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) before asking a question. A few print statements would have gone a long way to helping you figure out what's going on. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of disconnected snippets.

You should also try to use standard naming conventions: variables should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin.
I'm new to coding and this is my first question.
I'll be sure to include more info next time.

Comment: @MaxwellGreene No problem. Note that you can [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find them helpful. Happy coding.